# What does the line '!/bin/sh -e' do?

Tags: linux, shell

In the beginning of a file on my server (linux), which is located in the /etc/init.d/ folder I have this line:

```
 !/bin/sh -e
```

What does it mean, because every time I execute the rest of the script it works fine except for an error which shows:

```
 !/bin/sh not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As yet, no one has addressed the `-e`, which does not appear to be a flag accepted by the bash on my MacBook.

Comment: @dmckee: sh != bash.  `man sh` (or `man dash`) shows `-e errexit: If not interactive, exit immediately if any untested command fails...`

Comment: By the way @Camran, the reason it still runs without fixing the shebang line is probably because you're calling the shell interpreter directly, e.g. `sh myScript`.  With the shebang line, you could set the file to be executable using `chmod +x...` and run it without calling the interpreter explicitly.

Comment: @Mark: I know. But Mac OS X doesn't come with a plain ol' bourne shell, and I didn't have a linux box handy...

Answer (score 32):

That line defines what program will execute the given script.
For `sh` normally that line should start with the # character as so:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
```

The -e flag's long name is `errexit`, causing the script to immediately exit on the first error. A more detailed description from `man sh`:

> If not interactive, exit immediately if any untested command fails.  The exit status of a command is considered to be explicitly tested if the command is used to control an `if`, `elif`, `while`, or `until`; or if the command is the left hand operand of an `&&` or `||` [operator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Top answer is at best a typo comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
 #!/bin/bash
```

this is the first line in the script to tell the system to use bash shell to execute the script.