# What does '#!/bin/sh -xe' mean?

Tags: bash, sh

In the repository on GitHub of [Tribler](https://github.com/Tribler/tribler), I see a [file](https://github.com/Tribler/tribler/blob/devel/mac/makedistmac_64bit.sh) with the interpreter: `#!/bin/sh -xe`.

On Mac and Linux `man sh` redirects to `BASH(1)` (same as `man bash`).

In this man file, under the section:

> OPTIONS

,there is no mention of an option `-x` , nor an option `-e`.

What is the meaning of the interpreter `#!/bin/sh -xe` ?

Comment: for `-e` there's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34097445/9858236)

Comment: The first line in the `OPTIONS` session says that you can use all the options  (including `-x` and `-e`) documented under the `set` built-in when starting `bash`. The flags that follow are just *additional* flags.=

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this:

`man sh`:

```
-x xtrace        Write each command to standard error (preceded by
                            a ‘+ ’) before it is executed.  Useful for debug‐
                            ging.


-e errexit       If not interactive, exit immediately if any
                            untested command fails.  The exit status of a com‐
                            mand is considered to be explicitly tested if the
                            command is used to control an if, elif, while, or
                            until; or if the command is the left hand operand
                            of an “&&” or “||” operator.
```

It seems these are just error control options that make sure nothing worse happens if a command fails.

Comment: Note that using `-e` can be **very** counterproductive, creating bugs where none existed; see the exercises in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises), and the list of incompatibilities between how different shells handle this flag at https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/

Answer (score 1):

Per man page: [read more](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html)

> The -a, -b, -C, -e, -f, -m, -n, -o option, -u, -v, and -x options are described as part of the set utility in Special Built-In Utilities. The option letters derived from the set special built-in shall also be accepted with a leading plus sign ( '+' ) instead of a leading hyphen (meaning the reverse case of the option as described in this volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001).

when you read `set` man pages you get:

> **-x**    The shell shall write to standard error a trace for each command after it expands the command and before it executes it. It is unspecified whether the command that turns tracing off is traced.

and

> **-e**    When this option is on, if a simple command fails for any of the reasons listed in Consequences of Shell Errors or returns an exit status value >0, and is not part of the compound list following a while, until, or if keyword, and is not a part of an AND or OR list, and is not a pipeline preceded by the ! reserved word, then the shell shall immediately exit.